# how to add all arguments which are present in function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please tell me how to add all arguments which are present in function ?I tried like that but not getting success

here is my code

```
function a(arrugemt){
sum=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arrugemt.length;i++){
       sum+=arrugemt[i] 
    }
    console.log("sum:"+sum)
}

a(1,2)
a(1,3,5)
a(1,3,5,4,2,1)
```

**Expected output** :

```
3
9
16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions have a built in [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that contains all the arguments passed to the function

```
function a() {

    var sum = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
       sum += arguments[i] ;
    }

    console.log("sum:" + sum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks working..!! could you please tell me one more simple thing how to get the browser name ? window.browserName ?

Comment: hah i was little bit late :), yep this is the solution, but your code was with syntax mistakes and it looks like you do not look hard enough.@user944513

Comment: I don't see a returning the value to the call. Great for the console, bad for the script.

Comment: @DevlshOne - That's how the OP presents it, thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a function (and you could even prototype it, if you wanted to)**

```
function Sum() {
    var s = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        s += arguments[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var total = Sum(31,12,46,78,19);
```

This is based on the `arguments` object that is built-in to JavaScript for methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments